# Android : How to use compression for APIs to improve performance on slow internet connection?

Tags: android, networking, retrofit, gzip, okhttp

I am developing an Android app that uses Retrofit for networking. Some of the APIs that I use return large JSON responses(1 KB) that might take a long time to download on slow internet connection. I want to improve the user experience by reducing the response size and download time.

I have read that GZIP compression can help with this, but I am not sure if it will give any significant improvement.

What should be my approach to measure the size and speed difference before and after compression?

Are there any other techniques or best practices to optimize Retrofit/OkHttp for slow internet connection?
Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.